# mysql Different time intervals in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, intervals

We created a database with different kinds of equipment at our university that need maintenance at different dates. Also the interval of maintenance differs (sometimes every month, sometimes every 2 weeks etc.). 
Now we want to have a column that automatically updates itself if you change the maintenance date. What we used in general is

```
UPDATE table SET NextMaintDate = MaintDate + INTERVAL 1 month
```

As a result every date for NextMaintDate is one month after the MaintDate. Is there a possibility to use the different MaintDate to have different intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
UPDATE table SET NextMaintDate = 
  CASE WHEN type = 'monthly' THEN MaintDate + INTERVAL 1 month  
       WHEN type = 'weekly' THEN MaintDate + INTERVAL 1 week
       WHEN type = 'daily' THEN MaintDate + INTERVAL 1 day
  END
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error Unknown column 'type' in 'field list'

Comment: @Kiekster . . . You would have to include that column in the data.

Comment: @Kiekster: There must be something indicating what interval applies. I made an example with a column called `type`. Your record will contain another column or other columns you would use instead.

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL `5.7.6` or later, you could use a computed column in your table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MaintDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ...
    NextMaintDate AS DATE_ADD(MaintDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
);
```

Now whenever the `MaintDate` column gets updated, `NextMaintDate` will also automatically get updated (at least logically).

You can choose `VIRTUAL` or `STORED` for the generated column, depending on whether you want to compute the column on the fly or actually persist the data.

With regard to other intervals, you could just add more computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

You would modify your table to have two columns:

- `maintenance_interval_type` is the type of the interval
- `maintenance_interval_num` is the number

Then you can do:

```
update t
    set NextMaintDate = (case when maintenance_interval_type = 'month' 
                              then maintdate + interval maintenance_interval_num month
                              when maintenance_interval_type = 'week' 
                              then maintdate + interval maintenance_interval_num week
                              when maintenance_interval_type = 'day' 
                              then maintdate + interval maintenance_interval_num day

                          else maintenance_interval_num
                     end);
```

I should note that you could also do this using explicit types.  Something like this:

```
update t
    set NextMaintDate = (case when equipment_type in ( . . . )
                              then maintdate + interval 2 week
                              when maintenance_interval_type = 'week' 
                              else maintdate + interval 1 month
                         end);
```

This does not require changing the data structure.